# Can the Grease spell force multiple saves?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, saving-throw

The description of the [*grease*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/grease) spell states:

> A creature that enters the area or ends its turn there must also succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or fall prone.

What about a creature that enters the area *and* ends its turn there? That is, if a creature enters the area and succeeds at its save (or fails, falls down, and uses its remaining movement to stand up again), then remains in the greased area, does it have to make another save at the end of its turn?

Comment: Related to [Does Grease at most just cause one round being prone?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111416/does-grease-at-most-just-cause-one-round-being-prone)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes, Grease can trigger multiple saves

The description text for Grease states:

> When the grease appears, each creature standing in its area must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or fall prone. A creature that enters the area or ends its turn there must also succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or fall prone.

A saving throw is triggered under three conditions:

- When the spell is first cast
- When a creature enters the area
- When a creature ends it's turn in the area

There are no limitations on the number of saves the creature makes per turn/round. It's possible to force even more saves with clever play.

Spells that don't require additional saves due to movement, such as Moonbeam, state:

> When a creature enters the area **for the first time on a turn**...

Grease does not contain this text and can trigger multiple saves.

Comment: You could add that the area of effect is difficult terrain, and getting up from prone position requires 1/2 movement total. Both of these together increase the likelihood of at least one additional saving throw.